# How to show php folder in file in a 3 folder chain

Tags: php

I have a file (`/assets/header.php`), which shows fine in my homepage (`index.php`) when I use   `<?php include '/assets/clubs-header.php'?>`. However, when I use the same php include on an inner page (`/clubs/england/arsenal.php`) it doesn't show at all.

To get it to work I need to use `<?php include '../../assets/clubs-header.php'?>` but on a big project continuously changing this for pages isnt feasible.

Am I missing something or is there a more 'out the box' solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     $path .= "/assets/clubs-header.php";
     include_once($path);
  ?>
```

This will always start at the root of your file structure, you will just need to change the '`/assets/clubs-header.php`' to your own file path.